# Device Management from WAN with no VPN

Tags: osx-lion

We're setting up about a dozen mac mini's across the city that need to be managed from a central [lion-server](/questions/tagged/lion-server).

Our IT department is willing to open up some ports and forward them to our lion server but they are not willing to give us VPN access.

What ports do I need to forward to the mini server in order to manage the devices?

- I'm thinking mostly of when I update a profile and need it to be pushed out to the other devices.
- I also need each device to be able to authenticate via Open Directory when the machine is remote. Of course I'll setup "mobility" but I still need the machines to sync changes like new passwords when they "can" connect.
- Lastly, I'd like to be able to connect FROM the server TO each Mac mini via Apple [remote-desktop](/questions/tagged/remote-desktop). (The machines will not have static IP addresses on their side.)

Comment: As much as this sounds like me joking, I am being serious, open port 22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1629), I've discovered that

- Open Directory runs on port 625.
- Password server runs on port 106.
- Profile Manager runs on port 1640 & 2195.
- Remote Desktop runs on port 3283.
- Push Notifications run on port 2196.
- Simple Authentication runs on port 3659.
- Bonjour runs on port 5353.
- Software update service runs on port 8088.
- Netboot runs on ports 67 & 68.